# A special kind of rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unit element such that any ideal is decomposed as a sum of an idempotent ideal and a small ideal (i.e., an ideal in the Jacobson radical $J(R)$). Is there any research about such rings? Or Have been known?

Comment: I think questions related to mathematical research is suited more on mathoverflow. Just my opinion

Comment: A user named karpavar asked several questions on such rings, so I guess there is some existing theory.

Comment: I don't see how this question is at all unclear.